# IBM data staging product

Tags: datastage

Of the following tools, which one is more suitable tool for ETL?

- IBM InfoSphere Information Server manager,
- IBM InfoSphere Information server console,
- IBM InfoSphere DataStage and Qualitystage Administrator,,
- IBM InfoSphere DataStage and Qualitystage Designer,
- IBM InfoSphere DataStage and Qualitystage Director,
- IBM InfoSphere DataStage and Qualitystage Multi Client manager,
- IBM InfoSphere Fast Track Client

Comment: This appears to be a question directly out of one of those silly IBM Sales certification tests.

Answer (score 2):

`IBM InfoSphere DataStage and Qualitystage Designer` is the tool you use to design your ETL jobs.